# Logs issue of OSSEC installed on virtual machine of ubuntu linux in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-security, ossec

I installed OSSEC on virtual machine(node) of ubuntu linux in Azure by following https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/06/30/how-to-install-and-configure-ossec-on-ubuntu-linux/

OSSEC got installed and running properly but when tried to act as intruder, logs are not generating like syslogs,authlogs and alerts.

How to solve the issue of logs are not generating when I tried to perform as intruder.

Comment: Do you check these [FAQ](https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/ossec.html) on your side?

Comment: solved the issue by runnning command ,                                                                    /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control enable client-syslog